# Remove decimal ending zeros from BigDecimal

Tags: java, junit

I write test and want compare *BigDecimal* result with expected value.
I want use method `Assert.assertEquals(BigDecimal, BigDecimal)` because if drop it show exact compared values and in eclipse I can show comparison window.

So in code i have method that returns *BigDecimal* rounded to 2 decimal places.
In test case i now it return number without non zero decimal digits. So i want create *BigDecimal* with scale 0 and trim returned *BigDecimal* to same scale.

For more complexity I have now method `getDecimal(Object [,Optionaly int scale])` that create *BigDecimal* from any object with correct `toString()` value with default scale 99. I use it in main "heavy" code so this method must be very quick (Not necesary create another objects, dont use regexp, etc.).

So simple question is: how to modify *BigDecimal* instance to trim ending decimal zeros by minimal load.

Want srip like this

```
0.010 -> 0.01
5.000 -> 5
100 -> 100   not 1E+2
```

Resp:

```
someTrim(new BigDecimal("100.00")).equals(new BigDecimal(100))
```

Do math somthing like

```
100.00 / (2, 99, DOWN) * 50.00 -> 2500
```

And my code looks like

```
public static BigDecimal getDecimal( Object value ) {
    // null here probably work beter, but dont want number longer then 99 decimal digits
    return getDecimal( value, 99 );
}

public static BigDecimal getDecimal( Object value, Integer scale ) {
    if ( value == null )
        return null;

    BigDecimal result = ( value instanceof BigDecimal ) ? ( BigDecimal ) value : new BigDecimal( value.toString() );

    if ( scale == null )
        return result;

    return result.setScale( scale, DOWN );
}

// Main heavy method could call this 100 000 times per tenant (cca 1500 tenants), of course not expect all in same time, but can severals
public static myModify(E entity){
    return myModify( entity.getValue(), entity.getDivisor(), entity.getMultiplicator() );
}

public static myModify( BigDecimal value, Integer divisor, BigDecimal multiplicator){
     return value.divide( getDecimal(divisor), 99, RoundingMode.DOWN ).multiply( multiplicator );
}

@Test
public void myModifyTest(){
    // Constructor have param: value, divisor, multiplicator
    E entity = new E(new BigDecimal("100.00"), 2, new BigDecimal("50.00"));
    // Should pass
    Assert.assertEquals(getDecimal(100), entity);
    // Should drop: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<50> but was:<100>
    Assert.assertEquals(getDecimal(50), entity);
    // Not want: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<5E+1> but was:<1E+2>
}
```

Maybe exist another junit comparsion method that drop same error, but i don't know it

Thanks for help. Pavel

Comment: This code is terribly fragile. You should write two `getDecimal` methods, one that takes a `BigDecimal` and one that takes a `String`. Then you will simplify your code, a lot, and reduce possible errors.

Comment: BigDecimals are used best when not scaled, except when converting to a different type. You shouldn't be limiting you code to an arbitrary number of decimals. You should use `compareTo()` rather than `equals()` too.

Comment: Right, is better. But not sure how large can be Numeric in PostgeSql, and most of numbers we have limited to precision (17,2) resp (15,2) in java. Severals (?,4), so due to multiply/division operations i need some decimal reserve, but isn't necessary have all digits (not sure how hessian handle serialization -> how much data transfers)

Comment: Creating more methods with necessary argument will work, probably better without errors, but have methods for every primitive types + all another numeric types + all CharSequence types isn't appears good

Comment: You only need long, double, and String -- everything else can be cast by the lib's user's or automatically upcast by the jvm. That's 3 methods -- hardly overkill. Plus, you don't really need these methods -- like I said, you shouldn't worry about significant digits internally until you need to output a value in some way, then you should round/truncate it. E.g. If you do a division then multiply the results by a very large number the digits become significant according to the magnitude of the multiplicand, prematurely truncating the digits may change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably found a solution. Is bad to create 2 another BigDecimal instance, but don't know another less invasive method. I do little optimization to not create instance if not necessary.

```
/** 
 * For text comparsion or log propouse
 * @return human readable text without decimal zeros 
 */
public static String getPlainText( BigDecimal value ) {
    if ( value == null )
        return null;

    // Strip only values with decimal digits
    BigDecimal striped = ( value.scale() > 0 ) ? value.stripTrailingZeros() : value;
    return striped.toPlainString();
}

/** 
 * For comparison by equals method like test assertEquals
 * @return new instance without decimal zeros 
 */
public static BigDecimal stripDecimalZeros( BigDecimal value ) {
    if ( value == null )
        return null;

    // Strip only values with decimal digits
    BigDecimal striped = ( value.scale() > 0 ) ? value.stripTrailingZeros() : value;
    // Unscale only values with ten exponent
    return ( striped.scale() < 0 ) ? striped.setScale( 0 ) : striped;
}
```

Thanks to @frhack. Is possible write for test you own Macther class similar to OrderingComparsion. Simple for equals like

```
public static class BigDecimalEqualComparator extends TypeSafeMatcher<BigDecimal> {

    private final BigDecimal expected;

    private static final String[] comparisonDescriptions = { "less than", "equal to", "greater than" };

    public BigDecimalEqualComparator( BigDecimal expected ) {
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matchesSafely( BigDecimal actual ) {
        return actual.compareTo( expected ) == 0;
    }

    // You must change this
    @Override
    public void describeMismatchSafely( BigDecimal actual, Description mismatchDescription ) {
        mismatchDescription.appendValue( actual.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString() ).appendText( " was " )
            .appendText( asText( actual.compareTo( expected ) ) ).appendText( " " )
            .appendValue( expected.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString() );
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo( Description description ) {
        description.appendText( "a value equal to " ).appendValue( expected.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString() );
    }

    private static String asText( int comparison ) {
        return comparisonDescriptions[signum( comparison ) + 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [official junit solution](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/95) to this requirement is to use hamcrest.

With [java-hamcrest 2.0.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/java-hamcrest/2.0.0.0) we can use this syntax:

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("100")
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("100.00")
    assertThat(a,  Matchers.comparesEqualTo(b));
```

[Hamcrest   1.3         Quick   Reference](http://www.marcphilipp.de/downloads/posts/2013-01-02-hamcrest-quick-reference/Hamcrest-1.3.pdf)

Comment: This is good equal method for test approach. Better that assertTrue(B1.compareTo(B2)), but as i sad if i test method that return number with scale 99, than exceptions is not good readable.

Comment: Write: Assert.assertThat( new BigDecimal("100.1").setScale( 99 ), Matchers.comparesEqualTo( new BigDecimal( 100 ) ) );
---
Get: java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a value equal to <100>
     but: <100.100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000> was greater than <100>

Comment: @Perlos you can easily write your custom Hamcrest Matcher with custom mismatch error message: http://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/03/07/create-your-own-matcher/ (overriding the  describeMismatch method)

Comment: Yeap, best for test is to copy class OrderingComparison, and change method describeMismatchSafely. But how about licensing.

Comment: BSD License

https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

You have just to add a notice:

"Redistributions in binary form must reproduce
the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution."

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

Implement a BigDecimalToCompare as wrapper class of BigDecimal:

```
public class BigDecimalToCompare {
private final BigDecimal bigDecimal;

public BigDecimal getBigDecimal(){
    return bigDecimal;
}

BigDecimalToCompare(BigDecimal bigDecimal){
    this.bigDecimal = bigDecimal;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    return bigDecimal.compareTo(((BigDecimalToCompare)obj).getBigDecimal()) ==0;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
   return bigDecimal.toString();
}

public static BigDecimalToCompare of(BigDecimal bd){
    return new BigDecimalToCompare(bd);
}
```

}

test as follow:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("100");
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("100.00");
    assertEquals(BigDecimalToCompare.of(a),BigDecimalToCompare.of(b));
}
```

Another possible solution:

```
assertEquals(new BigDecimal("150").stripTrailingZeros(),
                otherBigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros());
```

Comment: For me creating wrapper around BigDecimal is strange, yes it work if  override equals method to compare method and override too toString method. Second give me strange assertion exception (number with E+n)

Comment: Why you don't like the wrapper ? take a look at the code updated.

You can use assertEquals(bd1.toDouble(), bd2.toDouble()) but it's much more heavy

Comment: Comparing doubles i won't because floating point/fraction it can be different value than i expect. You write exactly how i expect. But must remember this class, and share with team to know it. So remember 2 things. Besides what if i want log human readable value? I probably solve this by static util method who call stripTrailingZeros + toPlainString

Comment: @Perlos ok, please look at my fresh new answer.

Comment: I looked bud not see difference. Probably toString method should use toPlainString() to better readable output

Comment: As the wrapper is overriding `equals()` it should be overriding `hashCode()` too.